# Create a user programatically using Firebase Auth emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jestjs, jsdom, firebase-tools

I am trying to write jest tests using the Firebase Auth emulator and continue to receive the following CORS error.

```sh
console.error
    Error: Headers X-Client-Version forbidden
        at dispatchError (/Users/me/my-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:62:19)
        at validCORSPreflightHeaders (/Users/me/my-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:99:5)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/me/my-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:367:12)
        at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at Request.onRequestResponse (/Users/me/my-project/node_modules/request/request.js:1059:10)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:641:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
        at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20) undefined
```

The test is very simple:

```js
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks"
import faker from "faker"
import { useAuth, FirebaseProvider, firebase } from "./index"


const wrapper = ({ firebase, children }) => {
  return <FirebaseProvider firebase={firebase}>{children}</FirebaseProvider>
}

const createUser = ({ email = faker.internet.email(), password = faker.internet.password({ length: 6 }) } = {}) => {
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => user)
}

const signUserIn = ({ email, password } = {}) => {
  return firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => user)
}

describe("useAuth", () => {
  it("will return the user", async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useAuth(), { wrapper, initialProps: { firebase } })
    const email = faker.internet.email()
    const password = faker.internet.password()
    await act(async () => {
      const user = await createUser({ email, password }) // this fails
      await signUserIn({ email, password }) //and so does this
    })
    expect(result.user).toEqual({ email, password })
  })
})
```

And for reference, the index file:

```js
const FirebaseProvider = ({ children, firebase }) => {
  const firestore = firebase.firestore()
  const auth = firebase.auth()

  if (useEmulator()) {
    firestore.useEmulator("localhost", 8080)
    auth.useEmulator("http://localhost:9099/")
  }

  const value = { firestore, auth }

  return <FirebaseContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</FirebaseContext.Provider>
}

const throwError = hook => {
  throw new Error(`${hook} must be used within a FirebaseProvider`)
}

const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(FirebaseContext)
  if (context === undefined) throwError("useAuth")

  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const cleanup = context.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      authUser ? setUser(authUser) : setUser(null)
    })
    return () => cleanup()
  })

  return { ...context.auth, user }
}
```

I have tried using the REST endpoint that the actual emulator uses (below) and it errors in the same way.

```
http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<my-project>/accounts
```

Is there anyway to get this to run when using jest? Or do I need to create the accounts using the emulator UI, export them and re-import when I am running tests?

I have found I can use the REST endpoint below to make a user in the test, however it bypasses the emulator and makes a real user.

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=<api-key>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update jsdom version [16.5.2](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases/tag/16.5.2)**

This new version now supports wildcards for access-control-allow-headers, so updating to this version or using it as resolution, for projects created with Create React App, solves the problem.

**Solution for jsdom prior to version 16.5.2**

The error is thrown by jsdom because it doesn't support wildcard for access-control-allow-headers, but firebase uses the wildcard (see this [issue for jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2408) and this [pull request related to firebase](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/pull/291)). There are two open pull requests to fix this issue: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/3073 and https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2867.

The issue can be fixed by either changing the relevant code manually in the `node_modules` folder or by using the fork as dependency in the `package.json`:

```
"jsdom": "silviot/jsdom#fix/allow-headers"
```

If `jsdom` isn't a direct dependency, then you can add the following to the `package.json` at the top level:

```
"resolutions": {
  "jsdom": "silviot/jsdom#fix/allow-headers"
}
```

If the fork is used there are some auto-generated files missing in the `jsdom` folder. These can be generated by running `npm install` or `yarn install` in the folder. To automate this you can add a `prepare` script to the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepare": "cd node_modules/jsdom && yarn"
},
```

Comment: I have tried the suggestions and they all lead to the same outcome of an `Cannot find module './jsdom/living/generated/utils.js'` error. I have cleared the jest cache and deleted my node_modules.

Comment: Are there any known work around for using the Firebase Auth emulator in tests in the mean time while this is being fixed? I can't manage to find any online.

Comment: I've had the the same error until running `yarn` in the `node_modules/jsdom` folder. The output is: 

    $ yarn convert-idl && yarn generate-js-globals            
    yarn run v1.22.5                                          
    $ node ./scripts/webidl/convert.js                        
   Done in 2.97s.                                            
   yarn run v1.22.5                                          
   $ node ./scripts/generate-js-globals.js
After that the `/jsdom/living/generated` folder is present.

I also couldn't find anything online, except your question.

Comment: Ah yes this worked! A bit annoying to go through these steps to get it working... hopefully the required dependancies will get updated shortly to better support his.

Comment: [This is the solution I'm currently using](https://gist.github.com/silviot/4b062421a2bc6e128ffe666873060cda)
It patches jsdom after each call to `yarn install` applying [the changes of the (unmerged as of now) PR with the fix](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2408).

Comment: I have verified the new version `16.5.2` fixes this bug.

Answer (score 6):

I also had problems making users programaticly in the firebase auth emulator.

Instead of using

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]
```

You have to use the following format:

```
http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]
```

Then giving a JSON body like this, and hit post

```
{
"email": "test@test.com",
"password": "test12"
}
```

And voila! You have a user in your emulator. Combine this with fetch or axios and you seed your emulator with users. If you need to add custom claims or other info, create function in the functions emulator that triggers on user creation.

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate
```