# Firebase Auth testing with jest and emulator calling the login throws Error: Headers X-Client-Version forbidden

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to login a dummy user with the firebase js sdk localy. I have the default firebase emulator running. After calling the function i get following exception:

```
    Error: Headers X-Client-Version forbidden
        at dispatchError (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekte\Backend\functions\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:62:19)
        at validCORSPreflightHeaders (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekte\Backend\functions\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:99:5)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekte\Backend\functions\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:367:12)
        at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projekte\Backend\functions\node_modules\request\request.js:1059:10)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:641:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
        at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20) undefined

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at dispatchError (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:65:53)
      at validCORSPreflightHeaders (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:99:5)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:367:12)
      at Request.onRequestResponse (node_modules/request/request.js:1059:10)

  console.log
    t {
      code: 'auth/network-request-failed',
      message: 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.',
      a: null
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.ts:275:12)
```

If i try to connect to my online project it works fine, but i want to perform my testing localy with the emulator.

Example Code:

```js
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

app.auth().useEmulator("http://localhost:9099");
app.firestore().settings({
    host: "localhost:8080",
    ssl: false,
});

test('Example test case', async () => {
        try {
            const cred: UserCredential = await app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("foo@bar.de", "bla2377");
            expect(cred).toBeTruthy();
            expect(cred.user).toBeTruthy();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            expect(true).toBeFalsy();
        }
    });
```

Enviorment Informations:

- Operating System version: Windows 10 Home 10.0.18363 Build 18363
- Firebase SDK version: 8.2.3
- Jest Version: 26.6.3
- Node Version: 14

Answer (score 3):

jsdom doesn't support wildcard access-control-allow-headers, which are used by firebase. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65511295/14914693) fixes the exception.